# About HTTP_HOST & PHP_SELF

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, subdomain, http-host

i need a `if` condition, witch detects `main url`, for one of my important functions.

```
if ($_SERVER[HTTP_HOST] == www.example.com) { echo its a root page; }
else { echo its a subdomain page; }
```

my site`(magento)` is installed in subdomain; and im getting some pages from root via static php pages.(with `htaccess`)

now.. when I try `HTTP_HOST` in root pages(**www.example.com/about**), the value returns **subdomain.example.com** (!!??) - maybe because of htaccess or magento structure)

But I need 'hey its a root page' for example.

Can I use any more mothods which is not similar `PHP_SELF, HTTP_HOST` etc?

Comment: Is there a variable in `$_SERVER` that you can use to detect the rewrite from the www domain to the subdomain?

Comment: my root htaccess is this: RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

Comment: Dear Halcyon, i couldnt find any ready-to use variable.. but when i say echo $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST] in www/root pages, it returns subdomain adresses.

Comment: Can you show us your rewrite rules?

Comment: rewrite rules means httaccess in root? i wrote in my first comment. but its not the point i think.. it only make example.com/url to example.com/url.php.. the point is in the url.php's dynamic content (it get his content from subdomain by requesting blocks, functions, classes etc)